# In what contexts would you use "there was a time when..." as opposed to "there has been a time when..."?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

Would you tell me in what contexts would you use *there was a time when...* as opposed to *there has been a time when...*? For example:

> **There was a time** when I had to scrimp on things to buy a thing I really needed.
>
> **There has been a time** when I had to scrimp on things to buy a thing I really needed.

Are both sentences are perfectly natural?

Comment: I would use the first and not the second, which I don't find at all natural.

Answer (score 2):

No, only the first example is valid (I would also substitute "something"):

> There **was** a time when I **had** to scrimp on things to buy **something** I really needed.

You have to use some form of the past tense because that time is over. "There has been a time" is a form of the present tense (present perfect).

P.S. You can say "there **had been** a time," but it's pretty awkward and would only be used in a certain context. I would stick with the simple past tense.

Comment: Interestingly enough, "There have been times when..." sounds natural to me, "There has been a time when" doesn't.